# function not returning updated data based on updated state value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, api, asynchronous

I am creating a crypto react application and just trying to figure something out in which a function is returning an empty array when I update one of the state values. I am thinking it is a race condition. It works until there is a state change. Please see my code below:

So I have a state object. And it is returning an array of currencies by default based on the selectedCurrencyState.selectedFromCurrency value, which is a state value. This function basically needs to determine the quoteAsset before returning the object that contains the array of baseCurrencies. `swapInfo` is the state value containing the mock data. The mock data is nested like so:

```js
const getBaseCurrencies = () => {
  const filteredQuoteAssetObj = selectedCurrencyState.selectedFromCurrency
    && swapInfo.find(item =>
      item.quoteAsset === selectedCurrencyState.selectedFromCurrency);
  const currencies = filteredQuoteAssetObj
    && filteredQuoteAssetObj.baseAssets.map(item => item.baseAsset);
  return currencies;
}
```

Here is the mock data that I am using:
[image]

Like I said, it works until the state change of `selectedCurrencyState.selectedFromCurrency`(switch state from USD to SHIB). Afterwards, it returns an empty array. By default I have the state set to USD as the `selectedFromCurrency`.

Any help or input is appreciated. Thanks guys!

--UPDATED--
Here is the way I am updating the state by the way. I am using a functional component therefore, using useState.

```
  const [swapInfo, setSwapInfo] = useState([]);
  const [fromCurrencies, setFromCurrencies] = useState([]);
  const [selectedCurrencyState, setSelectedCurrencyState] = useState({ selectedToCurrency: null, selectedFromCurrency: null });
const [transactionType, setTransactionType] = useState(TRANSACTION_TYPES.BUY);

  useEffect(() => {
    getSwapPairs()
      .then((res) => {
        setSwapInfo(res.data);
        setFromCurrencies(res.data.map(item => item.quoteAsset));

if (transactionType === 'BUY') {
          setSelectedCurrencyState({ ...selectedCurrencyState, selectedFromCurrency: localStorage.getItem('fromCurrency') || 'USD', selectedToCurrency: symbol || localStorage.getItem('toCurrency') });
        }
        setTransactionType(localStorage.getItem('transactionType', transactionType) || TRANSACTION_TYPES.BUY);
  }, []);


  const handleInvertSelectedAssets = (fromCurrency, toCurrency) => {
    setSelectedCurrencyState({ ...selectedCurrencyState, selectedFromCurrency: toCurrency, selectedToCurrency: fromCurrency });
    localStorage.setItem('toCurrency', fromCurrency);
    localStorage.setItem('fromCurrency', toCurrency);
  };
```

Here is where I switch the transactionType:

```
  const handleTransactionTypeChange = (type) => {
    if (transactionType !== type) {
      setTransactionType(type);
      handleInvertSelectedAssets(selectedCurrencyState.selectedFromCurrency, selectedCurrencyState.selectedToCurrency);
      localStorage.setItem('transactionType', type);
      setAmountState({ toCurrencyAmount: '', fromCurrencyAmount: '' });

    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Feel like your problem lies in the way you update your state.
Maybe there is a typo on the updated `selectedCurrencyState.selectedFromCurrency` or maybe `swapInfo` is somehow updated in an invalid way ?

Could you fill in more info about how your state is managed ?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment. I just updated my post to show the states of my app.

Comment: Did not see anything wrong, however if `getBaseCurrencies` do return an empty array, then it means `filteredQuoteAssetObj.baseAssets` is an empty array. If one your find returned null your function would return null instead of an empty array. The content of `swapInfo` seems suspicious, I would log `swapInfo` in `getBaseCurrencies` just to be sure about that and if it is the case check if something did update `swapInfo` incorrectly

Comment: Hey @shantr, appreciate the input again. So I have come to a conclusion that it may be a race condition. I say this because when I hardcode the value 'SHIB' into the .find portion of the getBaseCurrencies function, the array populates. May be something to do with load time. Not sure if I can apply async/await into this but will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

When you update state in React,

The following should **not** be done

```
this.state = {a:"red", b:"blue"};

if( this.state.b == "blue" ) {
    this.setState({a: "green" });
}
```

Instead, do

```
this.setState((prevState)=>(
    {a: (prevState.b=="blue")? "green": "red" }
));
```

In other words, state updates that depend on its previous value, should use the callback argument of the `setState`.

Eg: `selectedCurrencyState` depends on `transactionType`.

You can store both (or all state properties) as a **single object**.